# uload child swf from itself

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I 'm trying to build a game in flash cs5, as3. The game will have a mainboard (mainBoard.swf) and from there I can choose what I want to play (loading different swf file each time). The problem I have is that I can't close the child swf from itself. The code I have wrote is :

*mainBoard.fla*

```
var gameLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var loadGameRequest:URLRequest; 

function startGame(eventObject:MouseEvent):void{

    loadGameRequest = new URLRequest("puzzle.swf");     
    gameLoader.load(loadGameRequest);
    gameLoader.x = 0;
    gameLoader.y = 0;
    addChild(gameLoader);
    gameLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener('unloadGame', unloadSWFGame);     

}

function unloadSWFGame(event:Event):void{
    event.target.removeEventListener('unloadGame', unloadSWFGame);
    removeChild(gameLoader);
    gameLoader.unload();
}
```

In *puzzle.fla* I have a "Exit" button and the code for this is :

```
exit_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closeSWF);

function closeSWF(event:MouseEvent):void {
    dispatchEvent(new Event('unloadGame', true)); 
}
```

As far as I have read, this is the way that I have to use, but it doesn't working. *exit_btn* does nothing.. Can someone help? Am I doing something wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace the

```
gameLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener('unloadGame', unloadSWFGame);
```

with

```
gameLoader.addEventListener('unloadGame', unloadSWFGame);
```

contentLoaderInfo is only for [loading](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html#eventSummary) events. For mouse events always use display list elements.

Comment: Thanks for help.It does work, though I get an error message : "TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.". Do you know why?

Comment: Rest of your code looks like working, this error comes from some other place ) It means that you try to call method or set/get property of object that is null.

Comment: after this changes your method _unloadSWFGame_ begin to works. I've check all the code above and there isn't Null Object Ref exceptions, so I assume that there is another code that can cause this error.

Comment: BTW, this error may occurs even in the puzzle.swf, for example if have some EnterFrame listener and call some properties of the stage, after removing it from mainboard stage in puzzle.swf will be null. Try to call _gameLoader.unloadAndStop_ instead of _unload_ this will stop all code in puzzle.swf and can prevent the error.